# XML TO TCL Parsing for Xilinx Vivado to generate Architecture

Tags: xml, tcl, xilinx, vivado

I am using Xilinx Vivado 2014.4 . i am doing a project to generate Block diagram for custom Architecture on Vivado . For that i want to generate a TCL file using XML document . I have exhausted all the Resource available on the internet but could not find any answer to parse an XML file to TCL Script .

An example XML file to generate Microblaze architecture with UARTLITE peripheral

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<System>
 <MicroBlaze id="0">
    <Parameter>
        <NAME>mb0</NAME>
        <ICACHE_BASEADDR>0xa0000000</ICACHE_BASEADDR>
        <ICACHE_HIGHADDR>0xafffffff</ICACHE_HIGHADDR>
    </Parameter>
    <Bus_Interface>
        <M_AXI_DP>axiinter0</M_AXI_DP>
    </Bus_Interface>
 </MicroBlaze>
 <AXI_Interconnect id="0">
    <Parameter>
        <NAME>axiinter0</NAME>
    </Parameter>
 </AXI_Interconnect>
 <Uartlite id="0">
    <Parameter>
        <NAME>uart0</NAME>
        <BASEADDR>0x40600000</BASEADDR>
        <HIGHADDR>0x4060ffff</HIGHADDR>
    </Parameter>
 <Bus_Interface>
    <S_AXI>axiinter0</S_AXI>
 </Bus_Interface>
 </Uartlite>
 </System>
```

How to convert this into working TCL script for Xilinx Vivado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is (usually) a general document description language. Tcl is a programming language. They're fairly different.

You can tell Tcl to parse an XML document. The *preferred* package for doing this is tDOM:

```tcl
package require tdom

# Parse the XML document
set f [open "theinputfile.xml"]
set doc [dom parse [read $f]]
close $f

# Get the interesting part
set root [$doc documentElement]

# Iterate over the child elements
foreach elem [$root selectNodes "./*"] {
    puts "I've got a [$elem nodeName]"
}
```

Which will produce output like:

```
I've got a MicroBlaze
I've got a AXI_Interconnect
I've got a Uartlite
```

How to transform this into what you actually want… well, you know that better than I do.